# String is not working with Switch case in JSP with java 7 and Tomcat 7

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I am using jdk1.7.0 and tomcat 7.0.27

A program of switch case with String parameter is working fine in JAVA but same program is not working with JSP.

> An error Occurred :   "Cannot switch on a value of type String for
>   source level below 1.7. Only convertible int values or enum constants
>   are permitted"

Any suggestions for resolving this issue.

Comment: it might be about project settings. if you use eclipse, there is a setting change compatible version. you can set "1.6" in there even you have 1.7. so, check project "Project->Properties->Java Compiler->Compiler compliance level". 1.6. can be used in there

Comment: You should avoid using Java in JSP. Better head for JSTL, here is one jstl example for a similar switch statement [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_choose_tag.htm)

Comment: As it says, you cannot have `switch` on string values, why not update JDK and tomcat?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you have to specify what version of Java should be used when compiling JSPs.

Add this `compilerTargetVM` init-param in tomcat/conf/web.xml (here I'm targeting Java 8):

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>fork</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>compilerTargetVM</param-name>
        <param-value>1.8</param-value>
    </init-param>      
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```